# How Hello Dolly plugin uses Wordpress functions?

Tags: php, wordpress, php-include

I am just starting to learn `PHP` and `WordPress`. there is a default simple plugin in WordPress called `Hello Dolly`.In its file `hello.php` I can see some WordPress functions like `wptexturize()` or `add_action()` but there isn't any `include` or `require` expression in that file. How that plugin can uses WordPress functions without including theme?

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: @rmc00 Its code  take too much space. you can download it from this link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add_action() and others (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) are part of the Wordpress Plugin API and available in the global execution space of your plugin.

There are tons of tutorials on plugin development online or check this out https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

**Edit:**

Simplified flow:

`Request --> index.php --> wp-settings.php -> (checks for active plugins) -> List of active plugins -> each list item (plugin) is included (basically your plugin index file) --> plugin index file uses plugin API`

So you can think of your plugin code as a part of the wp index file... everything loaded before is available to your plugin code as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I know this already, but I want to know the mechanism of availability of them.

Comment: Does it means that if we have 3 `php` files: `1.php`, `2.php` and `index.php`, if `1.php` and `2.php` are included in `index.php` then the functions belong to `1.php` are available in `2.php`?

Comment: @Gred Burkett  Tkank you guy, I catched it ;)